# Which VR headset works smoothly with Blender?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm about to buy a VR headset. My choices are: Valve Index, Oculus Rift-S and Vive. Which one of them is 100% Blender compatible? I must say I'm leaning towards Valve.

Thank-you very much !

Comment: Anyone would know something about this ? (^UP^) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, SteamVR (which also means Valve Index) is now OpenXR compatible.
All you need to do is to select the current Beta of SteamVR (in Steam ..)

Works flawlessly with Blender - no other setup required.

Answer (score 0):

apparently valve index + blender is a no for now.
but you may want to look at this: 
https://www.marui-plugin.com/blender-xr/
but i am sure at some point, someone will come up with something for the index. 
it's just superior in every regard that matters, so it would be silly to not include support for that.

Comment: All-right ! Thanks a lot for your light on this point !